# Fastest possible contagion algorithm with iGraph

Tags: python, igraph

I'm trying to write a contagion algorithm that:

1. creates an igraph graph
2. lits up four random nodes with, say, a fire (state = True)
3. spreads the fire to another node if a least 10% of its neighbors are on fire. The node which spread the fire it exhausted (state = False)
4. stop when no node is on fire.

Here's my code so far:

```
from igraph import *
from random import *
from time import *

def countSimilarNeigh(g,v):
    c = 0
    neigh = g.neighbors(v[0])
    for v2 in neigh:
        if g.vs(v2)['state'] != v['state']:
            c += 1
    return float(c)/len(neigh)

def contagion(g):
    contagious = True
    while contagious:
        for v in g.vs():
            contagious = False
            if v['contagious'] == True:
                for n2 in g.neighbors(v):
                    if countSimilarNeigh(g,g.vs(n2)) > 0.1 and g.vs(n2)['state'][0] == False:
                        g.vs(n2)['state'] = True
                        g.vs(n2)['contagious'] = True
                        contagious = True
            v['contagious'] = False

def init_graph(n = 60, p = .1):
    g = Graph.Erdos_Renyi(n,p)                
    while g.is_connected == False:
        g = Graph.Erdos_Renyi(n,p)
    g.simplify(multiple=True, loops=True)
    return g


def score(g,repl = 200):
    for c in range(repl):
        cc = 0
        for i in g.vs():
            i['contagious'] = False
            i['state'] = False
            if random() < .1 and cc < 4:
                i['state'] = True
                i['contagious'] = True
                cc += 1
        contagion(g)

t0 = time()    
score(init_graph())
print time()-t0
```

It runs pretty slow on my computer unfortunately, and I need to compute a lot of replicates. Is there a way to optimize this code, or maybe use a different method to perform a contagion in a much more efficient way?

I based this algorithm on http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC122850/

Edit: a run with cprofiler provides a little more informations. countSimilarNeigh() uses up the most ressources, by far:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  200    0.147    0.001    2.391    0.012 Untitled:14(contagion)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Untitled:28(init_graph)
    1    0.005    0.005    2.398    2.398 Untitled:36(score)
61392    0.601    0.000    1.925    0.000 Untitled:5(countSimilarNeigh)
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way to optimize the code :) But before actually doing this, you should profile your code to see where the bottleneck is so you could start optimizing the part of the code where the optimization would really have an impact. For one thing, calling `contagious()` all the time seems pretty expensive as you have just iterated over all the nodes in the previous iteration of the `while` loop, so you should know already whether there are still any contagious nodes or not - no need to check it again.

Comment: Did it: "countsimilarneigh()" is the criminal... :)

Comment: About contagious(), I think I found a way around it

Comment: You can probably use `get_adjlist()` to construct an adjacency list (i.e. a list that maps the vertex index to the indices if its neighbors) and use that instead of calling `neighbors()` repeatedly. This should be better because list lookups are way faster than method calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are duplicating your work. At each time step you check whether the vertex at hand infects others or not, namely you run countSimilarNeigh only for the vertex at hand. Instead you run it for all the neighbors of the vertex. Here is what I think the following code might work well. I have also changed the logic of the code. Now it's focused on the susceptibles and iterate through them. It's faster now but one has to check the results for integrity. My change in the countSimilarNeigh might have also made it a little bit faster.

```
from igraph import *
from random import *
from time import *

def countSimilarNeigh(g,v):
    return float(g.vs(g.neighbors(v))['state'].count(True))/g.degree(v)

def contagion(g):
    contagious = True
    while contagious:
        for v in g.vs():
            contagious = False
            if v['contagious'] == False:
                if countSimilarNeigh(g,v.index) > 0.1:
                    v['state'] = True
                    v['contagious'] = True
                    contagious = True

def init_graph(n = 60, p = .1):
    g = Graph.Erdos_Renyi(n,p)                
    while g.is_connected == False:
        g = Graph.Erdos_Renyi(n,p)
    g.simplify(multiple=True, loops=True)
    return g


def score(g,repl = 200):
    for c in range(repl):
        cc = 0
        for i in g.vs():
            i['contagious'] = False
            i['state'] = False
            if random() < .1 and cc < 4:
                i['state'] = True
                i['contagious'] = True
                cc += 1
        contagion(g)

t0 = time()    
score(init_graph())
print time()-t0
```

Comment: This is indeed so much quicker! About 20 times faster for number of vertices = 100. Do you think there is any hope for an even faster implementation?

Comment: You are pushing @Rodolphe. :) Joke aside, I think it is possible to make it faster. I don't have time to write it but I remember what I did for my infectious disease on network simulations. I maintained a list for the contagious or susceptible individuals. So, instead of going trough all the individuals in your network, you iterate only on the list of contagious or susceptible individuals. It should be much faster because when the number of contagious or susceptible individuals are not on the order of network size, the 'for' loops are much faster.

Comment: Ahah! Great!!! :) This is a very good tip, I'll try and implement it... Thanks a lot, really...

Comment: `contagious=False` in the `contagion()` function should probably go outside the `for` loop - otherwise it will only show whether the *last* vertex became infected.

Comment: Good catch, Tamás. @Rodolphe, if you use a list to keep track or contagious, you don't need to use the contagious variable. If your list of contagious is empty, that means the simulation is finished.